# Duda Chartjs grafico montado

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Realizo varias consultas a BD y dibujo un grafico(PIE) con chartjs y todo bien, pero hago otra consulta y tambien lo redibuja con la nueva consulta pero cuando paso el mouse por encima del grafico como que se monta el grafico que primero me salio,yo borro el grafico para dibujar uno nuevo de la siguiente manera:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("speedCanvas");
```

var contexto = canvas.getContext("2d");
contexto.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero no haber llegado tarde,

Algo similar me pasaba pero en mi caso cada vez yo ajustaba el tamaño de la ventana del navegador, desaparecían la gráficas, pasaba el cursor y se encimaban la antigua y la nueva grafica, lo que me funcionó es borrar y destruir la antigua gráfica antes de que se dibujara

```
if (window.chart1) {
   window.chart1.clear();
   window.chart1.destroy();
}

window.chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {});
```

Fuente: [consulta aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/232970/123830)